# Is there a term for the indirect sponsorship of large corporates by the state?

Tags: definition

For example, unemployment welfare payments could be argued to be ameliorating the negative externalities of large corporates hiring newly arrived unskilled migrants.

Is there a term that covers this?

Comment: As it is currently phrased the question is very vague. The existence of laws and a police force also benefits corporations, but (unless you go with the Illuminati interpretation) it also benefits most citizens. The term that would also have to cover the benefits coming from these aspects of the state could be 'civilization'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In European Union's nomenclature this is called *'State aid'* (see [glossary](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/summary/glossary/state_aid.html?locale=en) on EU's legislation site for a quick summary).
The idea behind this term is to cover all direct and indirect aid, including economic policy. If the measure is selective and it distorts the competition, it constitutes *'incompatible State aid'*.

Besides the EU, I think the word you are looking for is *'subsidy'*, which covers both direct and indirect aid, or more generally, *'aid measure'*.

Hope this helps, if still relevant to you :)

Comment: I have also heard “corporate welfare”?

Comment: As I understand 'corporate welfare' is a journalistic/political term rather than an Economics term.